# Euclidean + Taxicab Minkowski Space is Finsler metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, metric-geometry, finsler-geometry

Define the function $F$ on the elements $(x,v)$ of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{R}^D$ by
$$
F(x,v) \triangleq \|x-v\|_2 + \|v\|_1,
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_p$  is the $p$-norm on $\mathbb{R}^D$.  Does $F$ define a Finsler function (in the sense that the Hessian of $F^2$ is a symmetric bilinear form)?

I can prove that this defines a geodesic length space by convexity arguments but I'm not sure how to show (or check) if it is Finslerian.

Comment: Any curve between two distinct points has an infinite length wrt $F$ ?